# How do I enable an interface to listen to multicast?

Tags: centos

I want to receive multicast traffic on the `239.0.0.0` network. The multicast traffic is sent on the same subnet as my CentOS 7 server. How do I enable my network interface to subscribe to the multicast traffic on the local network? How do I verify that the interface is subscribed and can receive multicast traffic?

Comment: Are you able to listen using "224.0.0.0/4"? And what is benefit of "239.0.0.0" over "224.0.0.0/4" for multicasting? (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3330)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be by default at the interface level, unless you've done something to disable `MULTICAST`.

```
# ip a | fgrep MULTICAST
2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
```

`ip link set ens3 multicast on` could turn it on manually, if it's been somehow disabled, though that would likely better be done via the `network-scripts`.

Otherwise, you'll probably need to delve around in `ip-maddress(8)` if there's a specific link-layer multicast address you need to listen for on an interface; `ip maddress show` should list the default ones.